# Commutation of 2 linear operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

I have to show that

$$\left[\hat A,\hat B^n\right]=\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\hat B^s\left[\hat A,\hat B\right]\hat B^{n-s-1}$$

Is it enough to prove this for $n=0,1,2,..$ and generalize it to the above equation? if not any hints as to how I can prove this by induction?

Comment: Shouldn't the power of the first $\hat{B}$ in the right hand side of the equation be $s$ instead of $n$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: direct inspection proves that $$[A,B^{n+1}] = [A,B^nB] =B^n[A,B] + [A,B^n]B.$$

Answer (score 0):

This is the general procedure for proving a result by induction:

1. First show it is true for the minimum value of $n$ (In this case $n=1$)
2. Assuming the relation is true for an arbitrary $n$ prove that it is true for $n+1$

Follow this procedure for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to show it for a few values of n. You can use induction to prove it for any value of n. Induction has three steps:

1. show that the equation is correct for $n=1$
2. assume that the equation is correct for $k$.
3. use you assumption in step 2 to prove that the equation is correct for $k+1$

Step 1)

n = 1

$[A,B] = \sum_{s=0}^{s=0} B^s[A,B]B^{1-s-1} = B^0[A,B]B^0 = [A,B]$

Step 2) Assume that the equation is correct for $n=k$,

$[A,B^k] = \sum_{s=0}^{s=k-1} B^s[A,B]B^{k-s-1} \;\;\;\; (Eq.A)$.

Step 3) we would like to show that this equation is correct (using Eq. A)

$[A,B^{k+1}] = \sum_{s=0}^{s=k} B^s[A,B]B^{k-s}$

We can rewrite the LSH as

$[A,B^{k+1}] = [A,B^k B] = B^k [A,B] + [A,B^k]B$

We can rewrite the RHS as

$\sum_{s=0}^{s=k} B^s[A,B]B^{k-s} = \sum_{s=0}^{s=k-1} B^s[A,B]B^{k-s-1} + B^s[A,B]B^{k-k} =  \sum_{s=0}^{s=k-1} B^s[A,B]B^{k-s-1} + B^k[A,B]$

I leave the last step for you. Set the new form of the LHS and the RHS equal to each other and cancel similar terms and then you will recover Eq. A which was assumed to be correct. Therefore you proved that the $k+1$ is correct and by induction the equality is correct.